# I can't get pip3 to work no matter what. I have Python installed, but Pip3 elicits errors

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-14.04, python-3.7

Title. I uninstalled and reinstalled python 2.7 a bunch of times, trying to install python 3.7. I finally installed it. But now pip3 is messed up. I tried uninstalling pip3 and reinstalling, no luck.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS VM for college.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have never gotten pip3 to work on windows or Linux, but one command I usually use to install is "python -m pip install [module name]" and that usually works for installing